# CS50 Week 4, Lab 4 - Volume. fputc vs fwrite

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to copy wav samples using two slightly different ways here. First way gives me correct output file sound and the second one - distorted sound:

*fwrite case:*

```
int16_t samp;
while (fread(&samp, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))
{
    samp *= factor;
    fwrite(&samp, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
}
```

*fputc case:*

```
int16_t samp;
while ((samp = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
{
    samp *= factor;
    fputc(samp, output);
}
```

I already know that it happens exactly because of `samp *= factor;` in second case. Volume properly changes when I use numbers without a decimal point, and sound gets distorted when I use floating-point numbers.

---

So my question is: *why it works in the `fwrite` case, and doesn't work in `fputc` case?* Both of them are *int* being multiplied by a *float*. How does it even work in a first case?

---

Here below is a whole program for reference:

```
// Modifies the volume of an audio file

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Number of bytes in .wav header
const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./volume input.wav output.wav factor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    float factor = atof(argv[3]);

    // Copy header from input file to output file
    uint8_t *hder = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * HEADER_SIZE);
    fread(hder, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);
    fwrite(hder, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, output);
    free(hder);

    // Read samples from input file and write updated data to output file
    int16_t samp;
    while (fread(&samp, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))
    {
        samp *= factor;
        fwrite(&samp, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
    }

    // while ((samp = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
    // {
    //     samp *= factor;
    //     fputc(samp, output);
    // }

    // Close files
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: Although fgetc() returns an int, it only reads 8 bits from the file stream whereas your fread() is reading 16 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`fputc` docs on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc):

> Internally, the character is converted to unsigned char just before being written.

When you call `fputc` your 16-bit `samp` is being converted to an 8-bit `unsigned char`. With [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite), both bytes are being written to the output file.